# Processing radio buttons in loop in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a loop that iterates 3 times. Inside the loop I have a HTML form that has radio buttons. I'm processing the input using PHP. When I echo the form data, its not showing the correct values. Is it a wrong way of processing the data ? Any help is appreciated.

**test.php**

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ?>

    <form action = 'test.php' method = 'post'>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="one">One<br>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="two">Two
    </form>

    <?php
}
?>

<input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['num' . $i];
}
?>
```

Comment: What says `print_r($_POST);`?

Answer (score 3):

Move your form outside of your for loop. You are currently creating three forms with one submit button (which isn't attached to any of them).

try this way

```
<form action = 'test.php' method = 'post'>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
?>
    <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="one">One<br>
    <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="two">Two
<?php
}
?>

<input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>
</form>

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['num' . $i];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use following code: Or you can use radiogroup array it is easier than this.

```
<form action = 'test.php' method = 'post'>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
?>
<input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="one">One<br>
    <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="two">Two
<?php
}
?>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>
</form>


<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
echo $_POST['num' . $i];
}
?>
```

Comment: ya okk i m sorry.. at that time i m on call.. sorry brother.

Answer (score 1):

@Cagy79 added additional submit buttons.. I have revised the code,

```
<form action ="" method='post'>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="one">One<br>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="two">Two    

    <?php
}
?>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>
</form>


<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['num' . $i];
}
?>
```

This works. :)

Comment: indeed, that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 forms without a submit button (it needs to be in between the  tags). You need to create one form with one submit button like this so all your data is posted to $_POST.

```
<form method='post'>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="one">One<br>
        <input type="radio" name="num<?php echo $i; ?>" value="two">Two
    <?php
}
?>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>
</form>

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['num' . $i];
}
?>
```