# can i use multiple radio button in the form like this

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

[image]hello

i am not being able to submit these value in my controller.
the code is as follows

```
<input name="status.<?php echo $data['LEAVE_ID']?>" type="radio" class="ace" value="1" checked="" required="" />
  <span class="lbl">&nbsp;YES</span>&nbsp;
<input name="status.<?php echo $data['LEAVE_ID']?>" type="radio"   class="ace" value="0"/>&nbsp;
   <span class="lbl">&nbsp;NO</span>
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: use array in name attribute   name="status[<?php echo $data['LEAVE_ID']?>]"

Comment: Did you checked with $_POST[] ?

Comment: using my code i have got that form but how to post individual name ????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing radio buttons in loop in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963930/processing-radio-buttons-in-loop-in-php)

Comment: You can append leave name to value of radio button for eg value of first  radio will annualLeave_1 and annualLeave_0 then from posted value you can explode by '_'  to get value and column name(leave name)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple radio use `array` in `name attribute` with `id` as a index `key` like this

```
name="status[<?php echo $data['LEAVE_ID']?>]"
```

Comment: Actually i did like that n got that form but how to pass name of the individual leave name with yes or no.

Comment: set the value attribute value="yes"  and value="no"  and i you will get the leave id as index of array  . so you can use that id .

Comment: you will get the post value like this $_POST['status'];   array(1=>"yes",2=>"NO"....); here index 1,2 are leave_id

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using below code, you just have to add css.

```
<?php
foreach($dataArrry as $data) {
    echo $_POST['status.' . $data['LEAVE_ID']]."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```